# Libfreenect: Why doesn't the depth callback function execute?

Tags: c++, kinect

My problem is that is access the kinect with the following code:

```
#include "libfreenect.hpp"
#include <iostream>

freenect_context* ctx;
freenect_device* dev;

void freenect_threadfunc(freenect_device* dev, void* v_depth, uint32_t timestamp){
    short* d = (short*) v_depth;
    std::cout << d[0] << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if(freenect_init(&ctx, NULL) < 0){
        std::cout << "freenect_init() failed!" << std::endl;
    }

    if (freenect_open_device(ctx, &dev, 0) < 0){
        std::cout << "No device found!" << std::endl;
        freenect_shutdown(ctx);
    }

    freenect_set_depth_callback(dev, freenect_threadfunc);
    freenect_set_depth_mode(dev, freenect_find_depth_mode(FREENECT_RESOLUTION_MEDIUM, FREENECT_DEPTH_11BIT));
    freenect_start_depth(dev);
    while (true) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason i don't know, the callback function ´freenect_threadfunc´ doesn't execute. When executing freenect-glview which is a example provided by Openkinect, everything works fine.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: By "does not execute" - do you mean that you receive no output? Do you know if the function is called?

Comment: With "´freenect_threadfunc´ doesn't execute" i mean, the function is never called for some reason

Comment: Looking at`libfreenect.h` it seems like they want `freenect_threadfunc` to be of pointer type? Have you tried `void *freenect_threadfunc(...)`?

Comment: @darclander Then i cannot set freenect_threadfunc to be the callback function with freenect_set_depth_callback, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try to print anything in the `freenect_threadfunc` to make sure `d[0]`, is not zero? And instead of changing the method to pointer type have you tried changing its parameter to `freenect_set_depth_callback(dev, &freenect_threadfunc);`?

Comment: @darclander i have tried to print `d[0]` but it doesn't print anything because the function is never called. I also tried `freenect_set_depth_callback(dev, &freenect_threadfunc);` but i have the same problem there